# How can I validate on demand a flex 4 component size?

Tags: actionscript, flex4, mxml

The things are simple, I have a component and I add some content to it making it change it's size, immediately I need it's new size, but flex only updates the size in the next frame by calling updateDisplayList.......hou can I force it to update the size of the component right away.

Any thoughts? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naturally, I found the answer 1 min after, I was calling validateNow(), BEFORE adding the component to it's container. If I call it after that point, all's fine.